# Packet filter logging [currently with tcpdump in background as root]

Tags: firewall, macos, tcpdump, pf, launchd

I am running OS X Mavericks and use the "packet filter" firewall. However, it seems that "pflogd" is not available.

I found that you can create an interface named pflog0 and then use tcpdump to see the packets that pf has dropped. However, I would like to have a log file.

My solution was to make a launchd plist and create this interface on boot, launch tcpdump (as root) and log everything to /var/pf.log; it works perfectly.

However I am a bit concerned about having tcpdump running all day in root mode in the background, should I ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that tcpdump doesn't require sudo when listening on an interface (no special options) , I thought it did...

Anyway, I can just create the interface with a script in /Library/LaunchDaemons and launch tcpdump with an other script in ~/Library/LaunchAgents and enable logging. All works well :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know OS X Mavericks but i've tested it on OS X Mountain (not at boot) :

Edit file `/etc/sudoers`

Add the following to prevent asking for password :

```
youruser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/tcpdump
```

Start tcpdump in background and log to capture file (the main point here is the `&` that makes the command run in background) :

```
sudo tcpdump -i pflog0 -s 0 -B 524288 -w ~/Desktop/myfile.pcap &
```

To stop tcpdump kill it by retrieving its process id :

```
ps -ef
sudo kill pid
```

To open the capture file :

```
tcpdump -s 0 -n -e -x -vvv -r ~/Desktop/myfile.pcap
```